# Insert DateTime into mysql on chking the existence state

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I have a table tbltask

DateID int 
Fromdate int
ToDate int

My question is while inserting date values into database it should not insert if the date is already assigned,

for example,

```
 fromdate                          todate
 2011-05-20 9:00:00              2011-05-29 11:00:00
```

if i want to insert dates like,
from date todate

```
    2011-05-18 2011-05-30 9:00:00
    2011-05-18 2011-05-25 11:00:00
    2011-05-20 2011-05-30 9:00:00
    2011-05-20 2011-05-30 12:00:00
    2011-05-23 2011-05-26 8:00:00 etc
```

It must not insert
because from 20-29 i have assigned a task but in db i have it as only fromdate and todate

In a same date time may differ that should not be a constrain ,
for example:

```
2014-05-26 10:00:00
2014-05-26 12:00:00  // can be added if not exist in db
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
INSERT INTO tbltask (Fromdate, ToDate)
SELECT fromdate, todate
FROM (SELECT '2011-05-18' fromdate, '2011-05-30 9:00:00' todate) t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM tbltask t2
    WHERE t.fromdate < t2.todate
        AND t.todate > t2.fromdate
)
```